# on button click, show message for x seconds without alert() function - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my NEXT.JS project, I want a simple `<p>` element to show below my button for x amount of time, and then I want it to disappear. I don't want to use alert() function. How can I manage that?

Comment: What did you try? Some code here???

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a simple js event trigger. All you need to do is create a click event listener for the button, and then attach your 'p' element to the desired view.

Btw this has nothing to do with next.js this is core js DOM manipulation. You should learn about DOM and how to work with it, and then explore frameworks like next. Only with good knowledge of core js, and DOM manipulation, You will be able to really learn frameworks.

Comment: I know how to use onClick, my question was how to make element disappear some time after onClick event... :) hvala u svakom slučaju

Comment: Try setTimeout(), and set desired time after which you should execute .remove() on the 'p' element.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs it, here is the solution using useState and simple handler...

```
const [myAlert, setMyAlert] = useState(false)
  
  const handleMyAlert = () => {
    setMyAlert(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMyAlert(false)
    }, 5000);
  }
```

You can use it like this:  `<button onClick={handleMyAlert}>Click me</button>`

and for `<p>` set `style={myAlert ? {display: "block"} : {display: "none}}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late but I post it anyway to try the snippet method.

```js
function setMsg(e){
            let inter = alertMsg(e);
        }
        
        function alertMsg(e){
            document.getElementById("alertP").innerHTML="Click-me!";
            document.getElementById("alertP").style.display="inline";
            inter= setInterval("hideOutput()",3000);
        }
        function hideOutput(){
            document.getElementById("alertP").style.display="none";
            clearInterval(inter);
        }
```

```css
html, body{
        font-family:"sans-serif";
            font-size:1em;
        }
        button{
            font-size:1.2em;
        }
        #buttonContainer{
            width:200px;
            margin:auto;
        }
        #alertP{
            display:none;
            text-align: center;
            border:1px solid #000000;
            background-color:red;
            color:#FFFFFF;
        }
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
        <button id="clickableArea" onMouseOver="setMsg()">Alert Button</button>
        <p id="alertP"></p>
    </div>
```